# Composer event callback and number of committing peers

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have question about composer event function. Let's say ...

- I have two committing peers
- Business Network is deployed and an event is defined
- I also have client application subscribing the event with composer-client module

In this case, when I emit the event from Transaction Processing Function and the transaction is committed, how many times event callback function of client application is called ?
Two or One ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its emitted to each peer (so, 2). https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html

Applications can subscribe to emitted (published) events through the composer-client API will get a notification from each peer (ie each having eventUrl with defined event listener in the connection profile). Its up to the application to decide how to process them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried composer event with two peer environment, and I realized that event callback is called once for each event. I checked network packet flow between client and peers and confirmed events were sent from each peer to client. I'm wondering if it's expected behavior.

Comment: correct, it is expected behaviour from each peer.  The events are emitted by the Fabric peer.